# Is there an easier way to write this HTML code?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm pretty new at HTML, Is there any way to condense this code, this is only for a drop down menue.  I feel that it can be a lot shorter.  Also, I know there are a few issues with other things, I'm trying a few new things right now.  Thanks in advance.

```
<ul>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Home</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">About Us</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Who We Are</a>
            <a href="#">Histroy</a>
            <a href="#">First-Due Map</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Apparatus</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Engine 301</a>
            <a href="#">Engine 302</a>
            <a href="#">Squad 303</a>
            <a href="#">Utility 304</a>
            <a href="#">Utility 306</a>
            <a href="#">Engine 307</a>
            <a href="#">Antique Engine 309</a>
            <a href="#">Antique Hose Reel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Members</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Top Responders</a>
            <a href="#">Officers</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Calls</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Stories</a>
            <a href="#">Call Statistics</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Media</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Images</a>
            <a href="#">Videos</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Links</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Stations</a>
            <a href="#">Baltimore County Fire Department</a>
            <a href="#">Baltimore County Police Department</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Join LVFC</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Contact Us</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.dropbtn { background-color: #000000;
           color: #ffffff;
           padding: 16px;
           font-size: 16px;
           border: none;
           cursor: pointer; }

.dropdown { position: relative;
            display: inline-block; }

.dropdown-content { display: none;
                    position: absolute;
                    background-color: #f9f9f9;
                    min-width: 160px;
                    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); }

.dropdown-content a { color: #000000;
                      padding: 12px 16px;
                      text-decoration: none;
                      display: block; }

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #D6B813}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content { display: block; }

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn { background-color: #D6B813;
                           color: #000000; }

ul { background-color: #000000; }
```

Comment: What is your reason for wanting it shorter? Also, have you tried the code in a server to see if it works? Is it possible for you to include css, it would help us to help you.

Comment: consider using ul and li instead of such amount of divs.

Comment: you can do this from server side ... generate with a loop maybe (php or whatever )

Comment: Ok, I added the css, and I feel like I shouldn't have to include that many div elements.

Comment: Common practice is to use `<ul>` or `<ol>` along with `<li>` rather than all the `<div>`s you are using.  "Home", "About Us", "Apparatus" etc is a _list_ of top-level picks,  "Engine 301", "Engine 301", "Squad 303" is a _second-level_ list (a sub-menu).  An `<li>` contains an `<a>` for a menu-pick, or a `<ul>` for a sub menu. Enclose the whole thing in a `<nav>` for HTML5

Comment: Usually you don't write a lot of code to create something, you simply write more code to be able to make it look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right - it CAN be shorter. But it certainly can't be done with HTML only. You say you're new to HTML and you might not be willing to do this. But if you have an idea of Javascript, then you have either of two options:

1. Use Javascript/jQuery to store all link's text in an array and create them at run-time.
2. Use AngularJS to do the same thing mentioned in Point #1. (Coz, it's a lot effective).

Sample using jQuery:

```
<div class="dropdown-content"></div>

------------------------------------

LinkTexts = ["Engine 301","Engine 302","Squad 303","Utility 304","Utility 306"]; /*Array Variable*/
for(i=0;i<LinkTexts.length;i++)
    $(".dropdown-content").append("<a href='#'>"+LinkTexts[i]+"</a>");
```

Output:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Engine 301</a>
    <a href="#">Engine 302</a>
    <a href="#">Squad 303</a>
    <a href="#">Utility 304</a>
    <a href="#">Utility 306</a>
</div>
```

Sample using AngularJS:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#" ng-repeat="x in LinkTexts">{{x}}</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.LinkTexts = ["Engine 301","Engine 302","Squad 303","Utility 304","Utility 306"]; /*Scope Array Variable*/
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Output:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Engine 301</a>
    <a href="#">Engine 302</a>
    <a href="#">Squad 303</a>
    <a href="#">Utility 304</a>
    <a href="#">Utility 306</a>
</div>
```

Now, you might wonder "How is 'extra bits' of code supposed to make things easy?".
One advantage with AngularJS is that as soon as there is a change in a scope variable, the change gets reflected everywhere, automatically and instantly.

For example, if you add another value to the scope array variable, it automatically gets added under the dropdown-content div as a hyperlink (pretty cool huh?). This way, creating hundreds of repeated tags becomes easy (imagine creating a table!).

On the contrary, to achieve the same with Javascript/jQuery we'll have to trigger a function to add the newly added variable into the document.

So, now it's all upto you - what's it gonna be?

Comment: Just in case you need a reference or a place to begin with:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/

Answer (score 0):

By "writing" html, yes that is the only/easy way to do it. If you are up for the challenge, you could learn some PHP. With this language, you could write your entire navigation as an object like this:

```
[
  { title: 'Home', href: '/home' },
  { title: 'About', href: '/about' },
  ...
]
```

and then have PHP turn that object into html dynamically.

Here is a simple tutorial on how to do it: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2001/05/03/php_foundations.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have knowledge then you can use it to write the iterative code which generates HTML code using JSON. CHeck the below example.

```js
var listItems = "";

var links = {
  "Engine 301": "#",
  "Engine 302": "#",
  "Squad 303": "#",
  "Utility 304": "#",
  "Utility 306": "#",
  "Engine 307": "#",
  "Antique Engine 309": "#",
  "Antique Hose Reel": "#"
};

var keys = Object.keys(links);

for (var index in keys) {
  listItems += "<li><a href=" + links[keys[index]] + ">" + keys[index] + "</a></li>";
}
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = listItems;
```

```html
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```